# Providing private key for SGEN

Tags: digital-certificate, sign, sgen

My .NET assembly is signed with digital certificate from comodo. I use SGEN to generate serialization assembly. SGEN requires a key file in order to generate such assembly for a signed source. I tried the following lines:

```
sgen.exe  /force /parsableerrors /compiler:/keyfile:"mycert.pfx" "myproduct.exe"
```

but this says me

```
SGEN: error SGEN1: Unable to generate a temporary class (result=1).
error CS1548: Cryptographic failure while signing assembly' -- 'Key file 'mycert.pfx'
- Bad Version of provider.
```

I tried to get .snk which can surely be used for SGEN, using SN -p mycert.pfx mycert.snk and then

```
sgen.exe  /force /parsableerrors /compiler:/keyfile:"mykey.snk" "myproduct.exe"
```

but this says me

```
SGEN: error SGEN1: Unable to generate a temporary class (result=1).
error CS1548: Cryptographic failure while signing assembly' -- 
'Key file 'mykey.snk' is missing the private key needed for signing'
```

I read [over the internet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1493004/cryptographic-failure-while-signing-assembly-assemblyname-dll--bad-version) that this is SGEN error that it cannot use pfx to sign an assembly. So what can I do? Can I extract private key to snk file from pfx?

Comment: Luis, unfortunately no. I gave up.